# record video from browser screen or a specific html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, gsap

is there anyway to record the following animation as video in export it for download?
[an animation created with GSAP](http://codepen.io/ihatetomatoes/pen/QboVVV)

```
<div id="controls">
   <div id="slider"></div>
</div>
```

```js
tl.staggerFrom($boxes, 1, {y: '-=40', autoAlpha: 0, ease:Power4.easeInOut}, 0.5)
  .staggerTo($boxes, 1, {x: -250, autoAlpha: 0, ease:Power4.easeInOut, clearProps: 'x'}, 0.5)
  .staggerFromTo($boxes, 1, {y: '+=40', immediateRender: false}, {rotation: 45, transformOrigin: 'top right', autoAlpha: 1, ease:Power4.easeInOut}, 0.5);

// 4. Create a Slider to Control Playback
$("#slider").slider({
  range: false,
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  step:.1,
  slide: function ( event, ui ) {
    tl.pause();
    //adjust the timeline’s progress() based on slider value
    tl.progress( ui.value/100 );
    }
}); 

// updateSlider function + add {onUpdate: updateSlider} to the tl
function updateSlider() {
  $("#slider").slider("value", tl.progress() *100);
}
```

Comment: Not in JS code alone, no.

Comment: so is ther any way to do that?